# Targeting BEM-formatted CSS selectors with Sass

Tags: css, wordpress, sass, bem

I'm trying to slightly modify the styles of a block formatting plugin in Wordpress by overriding them in my own theme stylesheet. I use Sass but I'm new to it.

Pasting all of the selectors right out of Developer Tools works, but I know that's not the elegant/modular way to do it:

```
.an-accordion.an-accordion--v2.an-accordion.an-accordion--design-basic .an-accordion__heading { 
    color: gold 
}
```

What's the right way to do this in Sass? I've tried something like this:

```
.an-accordion {
    &--v2 {
        &--design-basic {
            &__heading {
                color: gold;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work. I can tell I'm missing something about the way `.an-accordion` repeats.

Comment: That is actually quite a good question. Took me some time to figure out a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the power of *local scoped string variables* `$something:...` combined with the power of *string interpolation* `#{...}` and combine it with the *current selector string* `&` to create a compound selector for any combination of *block*, *element*, and *modifier*. Which I think is quite nice and readable:

```
.an-accordion {
  $modifier-v2: #{&}--v2;
  $modifier-design-basic: #{&}--design-basic;
  $element-heading: #{&}__heading;

  &#{$modifier-v2}#{$modifier-design-basic} {
    #{$element-heading} {
      color: gold;
    }
  }
}
```

which will result in:

```
.an-accordion.an-accordion--v2.an-accordion--design-basic .an-accordion__heading {
  color: gold;
}
```

I tried it out on [sassmeister.com](https://www.sassmeister.com/)

Note that I omitted the duplicated `.an-accordion` class in the selector; if this is important for you to increase the specifity you can insert it with `#{&}`.

Answer (score 0):

BEM is about blocks, elements, and modifiers. *Block* scope is the biggest one, the *element* is some part inside the block and the *modifier* is optional and represents the status of your block-element. In Sass you can nest elements if they are **parent and children** and you **don't need to repeat the parent** element, in your stlesheet, if the **beginning** of your property is the same for **both parent and child**, but if the beginning is **different** you **must repeat**.

In a html like this:

```
<div class=" an-accordion an-accordion--v2 .an-accordion--design-basic .an-accordion__heading"></div>
```

You could have some scss code like this:

```
    .an-accordion{
        color: #000;

      &__heading{
         background-color: tomato;
       }

      &--v2{
         font-weight: bold;
       }

       &--design-basic{
          border: none;
       }
    }
```